# d3.js. How to exit() by value?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been trying to understand how `exit()` works (already seen Mike's explanations), and when I tried the below program, I noticed that the `exit()` does not take into account the fact that I've removed `3` from `dat`. It just sees that now there's one element less, and removes the last circle which it attached.

Is this how `exit()` was really meant to work? simply comparing the number of elements in the array and removing the last few? I thought it'd understand which values it's dealing with. How can `exit()` be programmed to recognize that the third circle has to be removed and not the fifth one? ie: How to make `exit()` recognize values in the array?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.node { cursor: move; fill: #ccc; stroke: #000; stroke-width: 1.5px; }
</style>
<body>
<script src="d3/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var dat = [1,2,3,4,5];
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",1000).attr("height", 1000);

redraw(svg);
dat = [1,2,4,5];
redraw(svg);

function redraw(layer)
{
layer.selectAll("circle").data(dat).exit().remove("circle");
layer.selectAll("circle").data(dat).enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", function(d) {console.log(d*10);return d*10;})
      .attr("cx", function(d) {return d*100;})
      .attr("cy", function(d) {return 100;});
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved it myself. The solution is in using [Object Constancy](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/). You have to specify an `id` which will help D3 remember which data value goes where. The add a function in the `data()` call which will return the `id`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.node { cursor: move; fill: #ccc; stroke: #000; stroke-width: 1.5px; }
</style>
<body>
<script src="d3/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var dat = [{id:"a", val: 1}, {id:"b", val: 2}, {id:"c", val: 3}, {id:"d", val: 4}, {id:"e", val: 5}];
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",1000).attr("height", 1000);

redraw(svg);
dat = [{id:"a", val: 1}, {id:"b", val: 2}, {id:"d", val: 4}, {id:"e", val: 5}];
redraw(svg);

function redraw(layer)
{
layer.selectAll("circle").data(dat, function(d) {return d.id; }).exit().remove("circle");

layer.selectAll("circle").data(dat, function(d) { return d.id; }).enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", function(d) {return d.val*10;})
      .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.val*100;})
      .attr("cy", function(d) {return 100;});
}

</script>
</body>
```